# How to detect whether a circle and a polygon overlap?

Tags: math, svg, intersection

I am implementing a function that can detect whether a circle and a polygon are overlapping or not.
I have all the points of the polygon and I know the center points and radius of the circle.

There I check two scenarios:

- polygon vertices are inside the circle
- circle center is inside the polygon

But there are other scenarios in which a circle and a polygon are overlapping, as shown in the attached image. Can anyone suggest validation for finding the intersection?
[image: circle and polygon not always a rectangle]

Comment: Note that these are two different things: just testing whether or not they overlap is much easier than to find the exact intersection shape.

Comment: but I need only to test the just they are overlapping or not but I could not find an exact logic for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach.

- If one of the polygon vertices is inside the circle, there is overlap.
- If the the circle center is inside the polygon, they overlap. Note that this test is not trivial for non-convex shape. For example consider a polygon similar to a thin spiral.
- Otherwise, for every edge (a,b) of the polygon:

  - Find p, the projection of the circle center to the line (a,b).
  - If the distance of p to the circle center is larger than the radius, there is no overlap for this edge.
  - Otherwise, if p is between a and b (so p_x between a_x and b_x, and also p_y between a_y and b_y, to include the case of horizontal and vertical edges), then there is overlap for this edge, otherwise not.

Comment: I know this answer was made almost two years ago, but could you clarify what you mean by the last bullet point? Isn't it guaranteed that `p` will be between `a` and `b`, since `p` is a projection of the circle's center point onto the line `(a,b)`? Won't `p` always be a point somewhere on the line `(a,b)`?

Comment: @JensB, the projection will be on the (infinitely long) line, but not necessarily on the line segment.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I thought that you by `line(a,b)` meant a line segment stretching from `a` to `b`. Thanks for clearing it up!